# get all the values in where clause for empty stirng using hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

i am building a shopping cart using jsp and hibernate.

i am filtering the content by brand size and price using checkboxes
the checked checkboxes are returned to the class where hql query exists.
so i want i single hql query that can handle this.

as like if one of the parameter like size is empty (means user doesnt uses it to filter the content ) than an empty string is passed to the hql query which returns any value...

so is there anything possible that all values can be retrived in where clause for empty string or some other alternative except coding different methods for different parameter...

Comment: Yes. You can write another query with no constraint.

Comment: What is "brand size", or do you mean "brand, size, and price"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically use the Criteria api for things like this... if the user does not specify a size, do not add it to the criteria query.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MyClass.class);
if(size != null && !size.isEmpty()){
     criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("size", size);
}
```

To have multiple restrictions via an OR statement, you use Disjunction. For an AND, you use Conjunction.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MyClass.class);
Disjunction sizeDisjunction = Restrictions.disjunction();

String[] sizes = { "small", "medium", "large" };
for(int i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++){
   sizeDisjunction.add(Restrictions.eq("size", sizes[i]);
}
criteria.add(sizeDisjunction );
```

Comment: how to use array in it or multiple values in size ?

Comment: Updated answer with example with multiple values for size.

Comment: i have used restricated with In and works well .. anyways thanks a lot for giving the idea of criteria

Answer (score 0):

First, good practices say that instead of passing and empty String to the query, you should pass null instead. That said, this hql should help you:

```
from Product p 
where p.brand = coalesce(:brand, p.brand) 
and p.size = coalesce(:size, p.size) 
and p.price = coalesce (:price, p.price)
```

Comment: how can i get all the values in p.brand when :brand is null ??

Comment: The coalesce function works as a ternary, comparing the first parameter with null. So, this is equivalent to `:brand = null ? p.brand : :brand`. So, if :brand is null, p.brand  will be compared with itself and always return true.

Comment: it gives null pointer exception since i m using array and i have to use setparameterlist("size",size) ...